# what does とつて in the context of エサとつてくる mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I want to break the sentence エサとつてくる into different parts. It is translated as "I'm going to get some food"

エサ means bait or food(relating to animals).
くる means come or will come.

but I'm struggeling with the とつて part. Bing and babelfish translate it with "and shall be" but this doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a small error. That should be a 'っ', not a 'つ'.

> 餌{えさ}取{と}って来{く}る。

It now means "[I'll] get some bait then come back."
〜ってくる is quite a common structure in Japanese with other verbs, showing you'll do the action then come back (in this case getting the bait, then returning).